# MySQL - return users that signed up within 10 days

Tags: mysql, sql

select email, users
left join clicks cl on c.campaign_key = cl.campaign_key
where datediff(c.Email_drop_date,cl.click_date) < 10

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the number of clicks per *campaign*, I would expect:

```
select c.campaign_key, count(cl.click_date)
from campaign c left join
     clicks cl
     on c.campaign_key = cl.campaign_key
where cl.click_date >= c.Email_drop_date and
      cl.click_date < date_add(c.Email_drop_date, interval 10 day)
group by c.campaign_key;
```

Comment: @cpat21 . . . Sometimes `date_add()` works better than adding an interval.  You should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.